# Populate Combobox(form control) using VBA on Excel 2013

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I am new to VBA. I have been trying for hours now to execute a simple function of populating a combobox(form control) using VBA code. I have looked on a lot of websites(including this one), but none of the codes seem to work. I have been using this code. (I am putting this code in a module)

```
Sub populateDropDown303()

With Worksheets("S1 Fuel Consumption").Shapes("Drop Down 303").ControlFormat

.AddItem "this"

.AddItem "that"

End With

End Sub
```

Hey I got the code working. But every time I select a value from the the combobox dropdown, it runs the code again and displays the duplicate values. How do I remove that ?

Comment: Can you better define "not working"?  Are you getting an error, no results, wrong results, etc...

Comment: Hey.. I'm not getting any results. The combobox dropdown is just empty.

Comment: Hey I got the code working. But every time I select a value from the the combobox dropdown, it runs the code again and displays the duplicate values. How do I remove that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub populateDropDown303()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Worksheets("S1 Fuel Consumption")
    With ws.Shapes("Drop Down 303").ControlFormat
        .RemoveAllItems '~~> This is what you lack I think
        .AddItem "This"
        .AddItem "That"
    End With
End Sub
```

I added a new variable `ws` of `Worksheet` type so Intellisense kicks in.
That way, it will be easier for you to see the available methods and properties for the object you're working on. HTH.

Comment: Hey yeah it works. Thanks so much :D And also, I have multiple such dropboxes. Can I populate them in one code only? maybe using a shape range function?

Comment: @user3756196 Yeah, you can do that. How do you wish to populate them? Where do you get the items you will add in each. If it is not that complex, you can even use a loop.

Comment: Hey yeah.. I used a loop :) Thank you so much

Comment: Hey L42, I need one more help. I am using the above code for 4 such dropdowns. So I introduced a loop in the code to populate these 4 dropdowns. Now the list has been populated but, whenever I select any item from the dropdown, it displays a blank.

Answer (score 0):

```
With Worksheets("S1 Fuel Consumption").Dropdowns("Drop Down 303")
    .AddItem "this"
    .AddItem "that"
End with
```

Comment: A link to documentation, and any accompanying text explaining what you changed will be very helpful.

Comment: I put the exact code in a "module" under    Sub PopulateDropDown303() It still isn't working..I just can't understand why :/